# Calling a method in Java using reflection, and obtaining the return value

Tags: java, reflection

I want to call a method using reflection.

The method is:

```
public String format(String text,int value)
{
    return text+" "+value; 
}
```

So, it has 2 arguments: a String and an int. And it returns a String.
How can I call it?

Comment: Well, how far have you got so far? Have you managed to find the method using reflection? Have you tried invoking it? What happened?

Comment: I tried to do something but I have a problem to continue
public String format(String text,int value){
  return text+" "+value;
}

Comment: Well put what you've got so far into your question, and tell us where you're stuck. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html or a similar tutorial if you're stuck right at the very start.

Comment: yes, now i can say good with this url docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/…  , thank you

Comment: Fixed title. Added the method from the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
        Class<?> type = Foo.class;
        Method method = type.getMethod("format", String.class, int.class);
        //as the method is not static, you need to have an instance of the class to be able to invoke the method
        Foo instance = new Foo();
        String string = (String) method.invoke(instance, "string", 42);
    } catch (Exception toBeHandled) {}
```

and replace the `Foo` with the name of your class

Comment: @aaron-digulla , nope you need an instance of the class to invoke a method as it's not static. That's why I had created an instance of the class